# Wrap legacy c enum to c++11 enum class

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, enum-class

I have an old C library and I have to wrap it inside a C++ environment. I use C++11 `enum class` because they're so useful and I'd like to do transform the original `enum` into a new `enum class` without simply create the new `enum class` and rewriting it. I'd like to do something like a `typedef` as in the old C:

```
enum num_oldc
{
    one,
    two,
    three
};

typedef enum num_oldc num_oldc_t;
```

But `one_t` must be accessible via its scope `num_t::two` exactly in the same way I can access a new C++11 `enum class`.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this with a `typedef`. However, you can do it as follows.

- Create your nicer `enum class` with entries that correspond to the entries of your C-style `enum`.
- Create two functions for mapping between your `enum class` and the C-style `enum`.
- In your wrapper API, use only the `enum class`.
- In the implementation of your wrapper, convert to and from the C-style `enum` whenever you need to interface with the library you are wrapping.

Comment: Can you please add an example or point to code on one of the opensource repos.